# Protect Form and Allow Track Changes

Tags: microsoft-word

### Track Changes is Disabled when Restrict Editing is Turned On

In MS Word there are options to protect documents, my (clients) document is a contract and so, for the most part, I'd like to protect it.

Like most structured documents, section-breaks are used to identify the various parts of the document:

> Section 1: Fillable form with fields that users enter data into
>
> Section 2: Terms and conditions
>
> Section 3: A place for documenting agreed variations

In MS Word "Restrict Editing" > "Filling in Forms" is applied to Sections 1 & 2 to prevent accidental changes - this works well. It allows users to add and edit text in Section 3.

The problem is that the ability to Track Changes is required in Section 3 AND the option to Track Changes is disabled while the document is protected for Filling in Forms...

## So my question:

***Are there any clever workarounds that will enable part of a document to be protected while another part of the document can be edited with track changes?***

---

**I'm all out of ideas, things I've Tried**

- Insert document as object - (not suitable, only shows first page)
- Master document - (not suitable, need everything in a single file)
- Locked Content Controls - (possible, but does not send the same kind of message as a password challenge)

Edit: And I should mentioned that this will ideally be a solution that does not involve macros.

Comment: Can you not Stop Protection on Restrict Editing, then go to Track Changes, then enable Lock Tracking, followed by re-enabling Restrict Editing?

Comment: I could do it with a macro, it was remiss of me to not mention a desire for a macro free solution. Other than that the contract is being sent to people who may be tempted to modify bits that should not be modified... so sadly unable to unlock...

Answer (score 2):

Enable Track changes first then enable protection.

Comment: lol - that might work... I can't remember if I tried it :-/

Comment: Actually, see comment for other answer: > my gripe is that enabling protection completely disables track changes

Answer (score 0):

Tracked Changes is either on or off for the entire document. It cannot be enabled to only function by document section.

I believe your best workaround alternative might be a macro that controlled the editing process in conjunction with the locking and unlocking of the protected sections and then enable/disable of Tracked Changes.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I should have mentioned that this will ideally be a solution that does not involve macros.  BTW I'm aware that Track Changes is for the whole document, my gripe is that enabling protection completely disables track changes.